# What is the HOUSE.PARTY achievement about?

Tags: achievements, bit-trip-beat

Bit.Trip Beat now has two new [achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/BitTrip/achievements): SUN.BATHING and HOUSE.PARTY.

Now, the Steam Summer Camp initiative makes it clear that SUN.BATHING is about perfecting 1-1, but HOUSE.PARTY remains a mystery.

How can you unlock it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `SUN.BATHING` is broken right now. I don't have any proof, of course, but the fact that [not a single person has unlocked it](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/BitTrip/achievements "Steam Community :: BIT.TRIP BEAT :: Achievements") seems to support this.

Comment: @lunboks The game's just updated. The achievement is now achievable.

Comment: Here's the description, for reference: "Experience the joy of a serene suburban afternoon"

Answer (score 1):

The house in the background reminds me of the one in GROWTH. My guess is that you need to PERFECT the stage in which it appears. If I remember right that's 3-7. Can't confirm it though as I only have the Wii version.

Comment: A little googling on my part seemed to indicate that this is correct (or at least, in the correct vein). Pity I can't jump directly to 3-7 in Growth. I'll try to verify this manually as well.

Comment: I can confirm that it is stage 3-7 where the house appears.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm posting a separate answer since you can't put images in comments.

According to an [archived message on the steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1969091.html), you only need to get a perfect in the subsection directly before the house appears:

> I just got it. When you see the house catch every beat before the long
>   trail where you have to stay in the middle.
>
> The pattern is one of the hardest to 'get' but simple when you know
>   what you have to do.
>
> The pattern repeats after the 4 positions. And maybe you have to be in
>   Hyper. I'm not sure about that. Good luck. ;)

[image]

After about a minute in 3-7, you'll hit a stretch where you have triplets of normal yellow beats to  bat back. After this section is a group of the teal beats, which is your target for perfect-ing.

Directly after the teal beats, the House shows up (and should, theoretically, award the achievement)

[image]

Given that I **suck** at bit.trip beat, I need to leave it for someone else to confirm that this is the correct sub-string of beats to earn the achievement.